# Apache kylin cube creation with rest API

Tags: hadoop, olap, kylin

I was trying to create a cube from scratch using rest api with a json file of cube definition, i tried curl commands to the rest api which doesn't seem to work and i tried using their kylin client tool and even that fails to create a cube,so i am wondering if its possible to create a project, model and cube from rest api?

```
curl -b /home/raghu/cookiefile.txt -X PUT -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8' -data @/home/raghu/cube_def.json http://1.1.1.1:7070/kylin/api/cubes/test_cube/build
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create project/model/cube with the rest API, because Kylin web is communicating with backend through the rest API. You can study how it works in Chrom's console.

But I would recommend you to create them from Kylin's web GUI, as there are some logic and validations in the front-end code. The structure of Cube definition is inclined to change in the future version, then you may need to update your client code if not using Kylin's web GUI.